# jQuery best practice - using selectors vs function(variable)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a general question about best practice in jQuery syntax/code organisation.

Consider the following snippet, used in a jQuery AJAX function:

```
if(obj.status == "error"){
 $("#alert").html(obj.message);
}
```

I have also seen this written as:

```
function alert_box(str)
{
  var html_str = '';
  $("#alert").html(html_str);
}

if(obj.status == "error"){
alert_box(obj.message);
}
```

Functionally, this is precisely the same. My question: Is there any semantic or practical reason for differentiating between the two? What about load time / performance issues?

Comment: `html_str` will probably be null in the second case.

Comment: This has nothing to do with syntax but with code organization. Of course putting logic into a function makes sense if you are going to use the same logic in multiple places. [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Comment: The first is better `kiss` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is seems to be a question of "why use functions in general"? The idea behind a function is that you're making a code block reusable without having to write out the same code again. If you want to do that same thing in several places throughout your script, the function makes sense. If you only do that once, it may not be as practical. Then again, functions also help you hide details where you don't care about them - so you can summarize an action while the details of that action are somewhere in that function definition.

In this specific case, that function is broken anyway. Rather than using the passed in argument `str`, you have an empty variable `html_str` that you're replacing the html contents of an element with. Also, there's no need here to use `html` rather than `text`, which is better performance.

```
function alert_box(str) {
  $("#alert").text(str);
}
```

Even though this is only a one liner, this can still be practical because it would let you use `alert_box` in several places throughout the script and not have to change those places later if you decide to change what `alert_box` does. Even something like changing the `id` of the element would require changes in several places, for example.

It also worth noting that this function searches the DOM for "#alert" each time it runs. It would be most optimal to cache that reference like this:

```
$alert = $("#alert");

function alert_box(str) {
  $alert.text(str);
}
```

A few things that are great to study:

[KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

[DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

[SOLID aka OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)

Comment: It's a minor detail, but in case of a jQuery selector for an id, like '#alert', the overhead is not so much in searching the DOM, but in creating a jQuery object wrapper for the element.

Comment: @yitwail good observation. Even then, it's not a big deal, but I obsess =D